# In java, how to send an email using sendmail?

Tags: java, bash, sendmail

I need to use sendmail in bash to send my e-mail in Java. I cant use javamail due to configuration duplication...

```
    package fr.thales.edf.reportEmailAcrAcq.email;

    import java.io.IOException;

    import org.apache.log4j.Level;
    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

    public class SendHTMLEmail {
        private static final String SENDMAIL = "sendmail -R hdrs -N never -t -v <         ";
        private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(SendHTMLEmail.class
                .getName());

        private String fileName;

        public SendHTMLEmail(String fileName) {
            this.fileName = fileName;
        }

        public void sendMail() {
            String command = SENDMAIL + fileName;
            try {
                Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
                LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Envoi de la commande: " + command);
                Process p = r.exec(command);
                p.waitFor();
                LOGGER.log(Level.INFO,
                        "Résultat de l'envoi de l'e-mail : " + p.getOutputStream());
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                LOGGER.log(Level.FATAL, ex.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                LOGGER.log(Level.FATAL, ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my log file:

```
    INFO - Command: sendmail -R hdrs -N never -t -v < ACR_20130111_100744.html
```

But my program never send e-mail and sendmail command still running (even after 2 hours).
Another thing, when i use the same command in a bash script, it works in 5 minutes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
    package fr.thales.edf.reportEmailAcrAcq.email;

    import java.io.IOException;

    import org.apache.log4j.Level;
    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

    public class SendHTMLEmail {
        private static final String SENDMAIL = "sendmail -R hdrs -N never -t -v < ";
        private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(SendHTMLEmail.class
                .getName());

        private String fileName;

        public SendHTMLEmail(String fileName) {
            this.fileName = fileName;
        }

        public void sendMail() {
            String command = SENDMAIL + fileName;
            try {
                Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
                LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Envoi de la commande: " + command);
                Process p = r.exec(new String[]{"/usr/bin/ksh", "-c", command});
                p.waitFor();
                LOGGER.log(Level.INFO,
                        "Résultat de l'envoi de l'e-mail : " + p.getOutputStream());
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                LOGGER.log(Level.FATAL, ex.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                LOGGER.log(Level.FATAL, ex.getMessage());
            }

        }
    }
```

I found the answer on this forum :
http://www.coderanch.com/t/379834/java/java/executing-shell-script-java

Answer (score 0):

When you create a process from Java, you must also deal with its input and output streams. IN particular, a `Process` may not terminate unless you read all of its output from STDOUT and STDERR. [Here](http://steveliles.github.com/invoking_processes_from_java.html) is a description of the common problems; you seem to be suffering from the first of them.

Comment: just a trick, this is not due to STDOUT or STDERR. It was due to "<" symbol ... java replace it by "\<"...